# Where is the documentation of libfreeRDP source code?

Tags: open-source, guacamole, freerdp

I am working on Guacamole source code and I get stuck in guacamole RDP module, I know Guacamole use libfreeRDP for its RDP client, but I can not find some detail, readable documents about libfreeRDP, can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

A list of reference documentation is maintained at [GitHub Wiki pages](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/Reference-Documentation).

Check also the [homepage](http://www.freerdp.com/) and its [API docs](http://pub.freerdp.com/api/).